# Datediff format to 000:00:00 in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a column in my SSRS report which is calculating `Datediff` between two time values. Below is the query

```
=Datediff("h",Fields!TIME1.value,Fields!TIME2.value) & ":" & Datediff("n",Fields!TIME1.value,Fields!TIME2.value) mod 60 & ":" & Datediff("s",Fields!TIME1.value,Fields!TIME2.value) mod 60
```

I want the data to be displayed in `000:00:00` format. 
Can someone help me out in the formatting?

See the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
=Format(Datediff("h",Fields!TIME1.value,Fields!TIME2.value),"000") & ":" & Format(Datediff("n",Fields!TIME1.value,Fields!TIME2.value) mod 60, "00") & ":" & Format(Datediff("s",Fields!TIME1.value,Fields!TIME2.value) mod 60, "00")
```